# Syncing up CPT device with EEG recording

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, eeg, reaction-time, experiment-design

I'm working on setting up an EEG experiment that will be going through a battery of various cognitive tasks. One of the tests is a Continuous Performance Task and to conduct that we'll be using a dedicated device(QikTest) that runs the test while disconnected from the stimulus computer, then is connected to get results. From there the program does an automatic analysis based on the performance and EEG results.

Since there is no means of automatically marking the task onset in our EEG recording at the time of the trial, the current plan is to use a video recording that contains the beginning of both EEG recording and CPT task to align the proper start time based on audio/visual cues of both for analysis. Our camera operates at 60fps so frame-to-frame is about 17ms, is this going to be a sufficiently small window to sync the data properly to capture the relevant ERP data in the EEG recording? If not would an audio recording at a higher sampling rate be sufficient(both starts have well identifiable audio cues)?

Edit(In response to Robin's comment below): Based on previous research we'll likely be looking for ERPs in the 200-500ms window for this and the other tasks.

Comment: It depends on what type of activity you are looking for. Some effects in the ERP only last for 15 ms, which would completely dissappear with a 17 ms resolution. However, A P3 lasts quite some longer, but, the peak will smear out, i.e. will be lower and wider. Typical markers systems only have a deviation of 1 ms, so a 17 ms might be rather much, but it is not insurmountable.